# Null pointer when creating a unit test for JPAQueryFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, springmockito

I have this method to update a table in DB, it works correctly, until I create the unit test for it:

```
 public class ReferentialAdapter {
        private final JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
        
        public void enableServiceConfigs(String roleCode, String countryIsoCode, List<String> services) {
            QServiceConfigEntity qServiceConfigEntity = QServiceConfigEntity.serviceConfigEntity;
            QCountryRoleEntity qCountryRoleEntity = QCountryRoleEntity.countryRoleEntity;
            QServiceEntity qServiceEntity = QServiceEntity.serviceEntity;
            JPQLQuery<Long> countryRoleId = JPAExpressions.select(qCountryRoleEntity.id).from(qCountryRoleEntity)
                    .where(qCountryRoleEntity.country.isoCode.equalsIgnoreCase(countryIsoCode).and(qCountryRoleEntity.role.code.equalsIgnoreCase(roleCode)));
    
            BooleanExpression whereCondition = qServiceConfigEntity.countryRole.id.eq(countryRoleId)
                    .and(qServiceConfigEntity.service.id.in(serviceIds));

            queryFactory.update(qServiceConfigEntity)
                    .where(whereCondition)
                    .set(qServiceConfigEntity.isEnabled, Boolean.TRUE)
                    .execute();
        }
    }
```

configuration for JPAQueryFactory:

```
@Configuration
public class QueryDslConfig {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory() {
        return new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

but this test throw a null pointer exception when call the execute() for the update.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ReferentialAdapterTest {

    @Mock
    private  JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    private ReferentialAdapter referentialAdapter;
  
    @Test
    void shouldEnableServicesConfig() {
        String roleCode = "CA_ICS_HBE";
        String countryIsoCode= "FR";
        List<String> services = Arrays.asList("VT" , "CAF");
        referentialAdapter.enableServiceConfigs(roleCode,countryIsoCode,services);
        verify(queryFactory,times(1)).update(any());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're test doesn't define `referentialAdapter`. Please provide a [mre] and the stacktrace of the exception. Generally this means you didn't properly set up your mock. Also, I don't think combining Mockito and Spring in this way works.

Comment: As far as I'm aware `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` doesn't apply Mockito. Maybe you want `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead.

Comment: i've updated my question, even with MockitoExtension, it throw an exception when call the execute() method.

Comment: I rather expect a `NullPointerException` on `.where(whereCondition)`, not on `.execute()` as you haven't setup your mock, meaning that `queryFactory.update(..)` returns `null`.

Comment: i do agree, cause when i evaluate the expression of queryFactory, i see that templates and entityManager are null

Comment: That is the problem with using mocks. You have to configure the mock correctly, or it doesn't work. You may want to consider whether this isn't better served by testing against an actual database (e.g. using testcontainers-java).